# MongoDB Text Search with Periods

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm having some issues with the full text search functionality in MongoDB.  Lets say I have this:

```
db.test.insert({fname:"blah.dll"})
db.test.insert({fname:"something.dll"})
db.test.ensureIndex({fname:"text"})
```

Then I do...

```
db.test.runCommand("text", { search: "blah.dll" })
```

This returns both documents.  It seems as if the period is causing it to be: blah OR dll.

What is the proper way to search in this case?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried escaping the `.` with `\.`?

Comment: Yeah, sadly, that doesn't work either.

Comment: Try searching for the [exact phrase](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.4/reference/command/text/#search-for-a-phrase) with `"\"blah.dll\""`.

Comment: That does work.  Seems strange that I'd need to do that just to search for a term that has a period in it. Thanks!

Comment: @BenFortune Any chance you could put that as an answer? It just helped me out.

Answer (score 4):

As pointed out by Ben Fortune in a comment to the original question, you can prevent splitting by surrounding your search word with quotes:

db.test.runCommand("text", { search: '"blah.dll"' })

An important catch though is that doing so also changes the semantics of your query since every quoted word requires a match:

**'blah.dll something'** - returns documents containing blah or dll or something.

**'blahdll something'** - returns documents containing blahdll or something.

**'"blah.dll" something'** - returns documents containing blah.dll (required) and something (optional).

**'"blah.dll" "something"'** - returns documents containing blah.dll (required) and something (required).